# HTML vertical resizeable areas on the page

Tags: html, css, resize, vbox, hbox

I'm trying to create a page layout like [This](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=layouts_04.html)

But I am not sure how to achieve it. What I mean; in that page you can see there are two areas in the page and you can resize the areas using the bar between them.

Thanks!

Comment: what html you want to use? can you create a demo on jsFiddle(jsfiddle.ne)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's certainly possible. There's probably a JQuery or MooTools plugin out there that does it. Otherwise, I rolled you a simple example using JQuery that you can play with. See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QEkwN/2/).

Basically the HTML is like this:

```
<div id="left">Left column!</div>
<div id="verticalresizer">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="right">Right column!</div>​
```

And then they are positioned absolutely (extra CSS from example cut for simplicity's sake):

```
html, body { 
    height: 100%; 
}

#left { 
    width: 200px; /* default starting width */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#right { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 204px; /* width of left col + 4 pixel wide resizer */
}
#verticalresizer { 
    background-color: black; /* so it can be seen */
    width: 4px;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: col-resize;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 200px; /* width of left col */
    bottom: 0;
}
```

​
Then the JavaScript. First an explanation. Pretty much the code listens for the user to click down on the vertical resizer. Once that happens, it listens for the mouse moving. Every time the mouse moves, resize the columns accordingly and keep the slider underneath the mouse. When the user lets go of the mouse (mouseup), stop listening/resizing.

```
var left = 200; // starting left col width
var isClicked = false;
var startX = 200; // starting horizontal position of resizer bar
var isMouseDown = false;

// attach listeners to the document itself
$(document).mousedown(function() {
    isMouseDown = true;
}).mouseup(function() {
    isMouseDown = false;
}).mousemove( function(event) {
    if (isClicked && isMouseDown) {
        var newX = event.pageX;

        if (startX != newX) {
            left += (newX - startX);
            if (left < 0) {
                left = 0; // keep from moving the slider beyond the left edge of the screen
                newX = 0;
            }
            setWidthOfLeftColumn( left );
            startX = newX;
        }
    }
});

// attach click listeners to the resizer slider
$("#verticalresizer").mousedown( function(event) {
    isClicked = true;
    startX = event.pageX;
}).mouseup( function (event) {
    isClicked = false;  
});

// function to resize everything
function setWidthOfLeftColumn( value ) {
    $("#left").css("width", "" + left + "px");
     $("#right").css("left", "" + (left + 4) + "px");
     $("#verticalresizer").css("left", "" + left + "px");
 }
```

Comment: I think frameset is fitting perfectly for my purpose. But I'd like to know why do you not prefer to use framesets

Comment: @OlgunKaya -- Framesets are bad code. They're really old HTML that's been around since forever. [This is a good article about the situation](http://godbit.com/article/why-are-frames-bad).

Comment: I found this http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos.cfm plugin for jQuery. But thanks for warning me !

Comment: JQuery is a very powerful and very popular framework. There's probably lots of different plugins or extensions to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the HTML frameset tag.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frameset.asp

Comment: 1. Don't link to w3schools. They're wrong half the time. 2. Avoid using framesets at all costs.

Comment: I found this just before you write. But why does someone marked this a downvote ?